# Circular reference accumulator "err:523" or miscalculation

Tags: libreoffice-calc, accumulator

To finish my spreadsheet sequence I usually let my pupils write a little car racing simulation in Excel. At my new school I don't have Excel at my disposition, so we do everything with Calc (which is fine generally). However, there is something that worked fine in Excel that I cannot get to work in Calc.

I need an accumulator field that adds the result of a dice-roll (simulated by `=int(rand()*6)+1)` to get the current sum of all prior dice-rolls plus the current one.

This is possible if you activate iterative calculations. But with my current settings I most of the time get the following error:

[image: error]

The settings are as follows:

[image: settings]

I can get the iterative calculation to work if I set "Minimum change:" to 6. But when I press F9, the calculation is not correct. It always at least adds double the dice-value, but oftentimes a value that seems to have no connection to the show dice value.

In Excel this simply worked using the following settings:

[image: Excel settings]

Example:

Step:

[image: Excel example 1]

Step + 1:

[image: Excel example 2]

Is there any way to get this to work in LibreOffice Calc?

If not: How to produce an accumulator field in Calc?

Comment: Hm... let's see how that works out. Filed a bug: https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=114482

Answer (score 2):

I note  m.a.riosv's comment to your bug report and suspect that individual either has a different set up or is using a different generator for the values in A1.

Simplifying A1 to be an integer between `1` and `3` inclusive (keyed in not generated) shows the following (repeatable) pattern when set to `1` iteration and minimum `1`:

```
0   0
1   2
2   Err:523
3   Err:523
1   14
2   Err:523
3   Err:523
1   26
2   Err:523
3   Err:523
1   38
```

I am now more convinced there *is* a bug, and you are correct about the doubling up. Also about the significance of the 'Minimum change' (ie a value is only returned when the change is from `0` or *more than* 1 (ie when drops from `3` to `1`).

Incidentally:

> Version: 5.4.3.2 (x64)
>   Build ID: 92a7159f7e4af62137622921e809f8546db437e5   CPU threads: 2;
>   OS: Windows 6.29; UI render: default;
>   Locale: en-GB (en_GB); Calc: group

(and also on an earlier LO version and on an OO version).

The suggestion [here](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=117049) is that this has been fixed for 6.1.0.1 and up.

<sub>... or merely handed over to Google? - Sheets has what seems a similar issue. ;)</sub>

Comment: You observation lead me to try the following:

Iterations: 1
Minimum change: 6

Formula for A2: =A2+(A1/2)

A useable workaround that btw. once more proves the doubling.